# api/docker/<repoKey>/v2/promote. " missing signature key "

Tags: docker, api, artifactory

using "api/docker//v2/promote" to promote images, client gets error "missing signature  key". but when i copy or move images by web, docker client can pull the images correctly.

Does "api/docker//v2/promote" not work ?